# Comparing three functions and plotting specific regions

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

Assume that we have the following functions:

```
f_1 = ((x[2]/(5+x[1]))**((x[1]+5)/4))
f_2 = (5+x[1]*((x[2]-5)/x[1])**((x[1]+5)/4)))/(5+x[1])
f_3 = (5*((X[2]-X[1])/5)**((x[1]+5)/4))+X[1])/(5+X[1])
```

In addition, let's assume that:

```
x[1] = np.linspace(0,7,0.001)
x[2]= np.linspace(0,5+x[1],0.001)
```

I need to draw a plot which clarifies region under which each function is greater than the other two functions. `x-axis = x[1]`, `y-axis = x[2]`

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Is the index switching from your code to the picture intended?

Comment: Calculate fs and try `fill_between`.

Comment: @myradio my question is that how can I drop a plot that clarifies those regions I mentioned?

Comment: @Ardweaden, I just don't know how can I use fill_between when the region that I want to be filled is a function of my x-axis and y-axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of your issue is that as you mention your functions are 2D so using `fill_between()` is not your best option. What you should do is create a 2D grid then loop over the values of your functions on that grid and set the max values to a number representative of the function. Then use something like `contourf()` or `pcolormesh()` to color your regions of values.

This should help but note that I changed `x[1]` and `x[2]` to simply `x` and `y` and used an arbitrarily large region with a modest resolution:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


#Create the background x[1] and x[2] values. I used x and y instead
x = np.arange(-20,20,.1)
y = np.arange(-40,40,.2)

x,y = np.meshgrid(x,y) #Make the 2D grid

#Apply those functions on the grid
f_1 = ((y/(5.+x))**((x+5.)/4.))
f_2 = (5.+x*((y-5.)/x)**((x+5.)/4.))/(5.+x)
f_3 = (5.*((y-x)/5.)**((x+5.)/4.)+x)/(5.+x)

#Create an array to update with which function is the max
maxf = np.zeros(shape=f_1.shape)
maxf.fill(np.nan) #Fill with nans since there may be regions that are undefined


#Now loop over your grid and find which function is the largest
#If f_1 is largest, set maxf to 1, if f_2 is largest set maxf to 2,  etc.
for i in range(len(x)):
    for j in range(len(y)):
        if f_1[i,j]>f_2[i,j] and f_1[i,j]>f_3[i,j]:
            maxf[i,j] =1
        elif f_2[i,j]>f_1[i,j] and f_2[i,j]>f_3[i,j]:
            maxf[i,j] =2
        elif f_3[i,j]>f_1[i,j] and f_3[i,j]>f_2[i,j]:
            maxf[i,j] =3




#Plot the functions using contourf or pcolormesh
plt.contourf(x,y,maxf)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @BenT. You completely solved my question.

Comment: Dear Ben, would you please also help me with the undefined regions? I mean we know that if x[2] < 5 then f_2 is undefined and if x[2] < x[1] then f_3 is undefined. In these cases we just need to compare the other two functions. 
Another exmaple is that suppose x[1] = 4 and x[2] = 3, since x[2] < 5 and x[2] < x[1], then both f_2 and f_3 are undefined and therefore f_1 is the maximum function.

Comment: Instead of using `np.nan` set it to -9999.99 and rerun. Then after you run the loop convert back to `np.nan` or just set the contour levels for `contourf()`. If you have issues try asking another question.

Comment: Thanks for your great help. I just did it but the plot got very strange. For the simplicity I just set `x = np.arange(0,10,.1)` and `y = np.arange(0,20,.2)`. When  x<5<y<x+5 then f_2 is the maximum function and when 5<x<y<5+x then f_3 is the maximum function. However, the resulted plot doesn't show that.

Comment: What does it show? Check your equations are correct.

Comment: how can I define y range to be dependent to the x range.?I mean I tried to use 
the following code but it just did not work:

    x = np.arange(0,10,.1)
    for i in range(len(x)):
    y = np.arange(0,i,.1)

For example if x = 2 then I want y range to be (0,2)  and so on.

Comment: If you are having issues then try looking at previous questions regarding setting your limits. If you still can't figure out the issue then try asking another question with a reproducible example. I can't help without looking at your full code and the context to which the code is running.

Comment: I just wanted to see that if I want to define a variable which its range is dependent on the range of another variable, how can I do that.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean based on your example or why you would want to do that but sure its possible.